# How do I get vb.net to write and edit multiple records at a time?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to deal with phone numbers in an Access database using .Net

If My DB Schema looks like this:

PK ClientID
   CellPhone
   HomePhone
   WorkPhone

The .Net tools will work fine.  Except that I would have blank fields in my database.

The correct schema looks like this:

PK ClientID
   PhoneType
   PhoneNumber

But I can not get .Net to understand that I want to write 3 records if all the phone number fields are filled in or two records if two of the fields are filled in or only one record if one phone number is filled in.  Not to mention the problems I would have in an editing situation.

I have tried the second schema in Access and then using the .Net tools to drag the three fields onto the form.  Then I copied both the PhoneType and PhoneNumber fields twice.  Then I bound the fields to the datatable and field.

I got the expected results...if I enter more than one phoneType and PhoneNumber only the last entry is written to the database.  So My original question stands:

How to I get .Net to write 3 records to the table if I enter three phone numbers, two records if I enter 2 phone numbers and one record if I enter 1 Number.

Comment: you'll have general issues with drag n drop stuff, because it meant to be easy, versus "correct". If you are concerned with correctness, then eschew the drag n drop stuff, and dig further into coding what you need.

Comment: This question is tagged 'vb.net' and '.net', but the language in which you write code in MS Access in is Visual Basic for Applications (VBA). Please change the tag if you mean VBA. I would also mention (MS) Access.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy; the logic you want is probably not possible to implement using only drag-and-drop tools. Either VBA code or possibly a macro will be necessary.